# Return a list of students who attended the same class

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling with the logic behind how to accomplish the following query in MSSQL.

- I have a list of Classes.
- I have a list of Students.
- I have a list of Classes that Students attended (This table has a relationship to both a Class and a Student)

How can I return a list of two students and any classes they attended together?  E.g.

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
|Student1   | Student2   | Class Name |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|John Smith | Jane Doe   | Trig       |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|John Smith | Jane Smith | Math       |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: what would be input of your future query?

Comment: Ideally none if I could get all students back who have taken a class together. However, there is the option of providing student1 and student2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a self-join:

```
select c1.student, c2.student, c1.class
from ClassStudents c1 join
     ClassStudents c2
     on c1.class = c2.class and
        c1.student < c2.student;
```

If two students attended multiple classes together, this will return one row per class.

If you are using `id`s and not names in the tables (a good idea), then you will need to join in the appropriate information from other tables.  I'll leave that up to you.

EDIT:

To count the number of classes two students have had together, you would use `group by`:

```
select c1.student, c2.student, count(*) as NumClasses
from ClassStudents c1 join
     ClassStudents c2
     on c1.class = c2.class and
        c1.student < c2.student
group by c1.student, c2.student;
```

You can use a `having` clause to filter by `count(*)`.  You can join this back to the other tables to get the specific classes.

Here is how you can join this back to the original tables:

```
select s1.name as student1, s2.name as student2, count(*) as NumClasses
from ClassStudents c1 join
     ClassStudents c2
     on c1.class = c2.class and
        c1.studentid < c2.studentid join
     Students s1
     on c1.studentid = s1.studentid join
     Students s2
     on c2.studentid = s2.studentid
group by c1.name, c2.name
having count(*) > 1;
```

You could also do this as a subquery, but this is easy enough.

Comment: I like where this is going. Is it possible to only show people who attended more than 1 course together?

Comment: I have the group by and having working, but I'm not sure how to get the class names now because I cannot use it in the select list as it can't be part of the group by.

Comment: Hint:  Make the query a subquery and then join the other tables to it.  Is this homework?

Comment: Lol, not homework. Just a side project that I'm trying to put a tracer bullet together.

Comment: Is it possible to return the class name instead of the count? I understand that it would be 1 row per students per class which is fine.  But the key is only ones that have more than 1.

Comment: @endyourif . . . In SQL Server, it is a pain to concatenate strings together in an aggregation.  Either go with one class name per row or search for "string aggregation sql server" and learn about exciting constructs such as `for xml path`.

Comment: That's too bad that it needs to detour to something else, feels like it's so close!

Comment: I think I accomplished what I wanted by converting the above query to a common table expression and than using it to query the data I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the list for each student is easy, than you [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) the two result using `WHEN MATCHED THEN`

for example: let call classes that student A attend `SAC1`and `SAC2` for the classes for student B

```
MERGE SAC1 AS target
   USING SAC2 AS source 
   ON (target.class = source.class)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    --insert into result table
```

if you want list of all the student that attend the same class do this

```
MERGE studentClasses AS target
   USING studentClasses AS source 
   ON ((target.class = source.class) AND (target.studentId <> source.studentId))
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    --insert into result table
```

Comment: Are you able to provide an example. I have never used the Merge feature, or created lists of each student.

Would this work if the students only matched 1 or 2 courses out of 10?

Comment: Do the 2 lists need to be an exact match? I would like to know only the classes they attended together as they may take other classes and the lists wouldn't match exactly.

Comment: SAC1 is all classes for studentA , the same for student B  so no such case can exist. (since if the same class exist in both - meaning A & B took this class)

Comment: update the answer to show all student that attend the same class, hope it help

Comment: @Tristan I think your comment is not for this answer since I use <>